# How to change the resolution of a PDF

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

I have several hundred PDF files that I'm uploading to Docusign which will be turned into templates and then used for eSigning. The problem is that the resolution of these PDF files is too low, as you can see it's set at 612x792. This PDF is a vector so the resolution doesn't really even make sense since it scales infinitely. Anyway my question is this: How do you change this resolution to 1275x1650?

I have Acrobat PRO DC, Photoshop, and Illustrator but have no idea how to do it.

[image: Here's the info tab of the file]

Comment: As you said, if the PDF is vector then it shouldn't really matter anyway; what's the actual problem you're having? The size shown there is the document size in postscript points (specifically US Letter in this case); that is the size that will show regardless of the actual resolution of any content (you could rasterize it at 600ppi and it would show the same).

Comment: Hey @Cai thank you for the response. The problem is that when I upload this PDF to Docusign, it ends up using the smallest possible resolution and it makes it basically impossible to add digital signatures. Docusign has no way of specifying the resolution upon uploading, they recommend resizing the PDF beforehand. Also I can't simply convert the PDF to PNG or something like that because Docusign treats those file formats very differently

Answer (score -1):

1. Open the document in Design or Editable Mode.
2. From the Tools menu, select Document Properties. ...
3. From the left, select Export.
4. In the PDF area, select the Use bitmaps for graphs check box.